# Extracting SAP SQL Anywhere .db/.log database files with free unix tools?

Tags: sybase, sqlanywhere, sap-iq

I've recently gotten a copy of a SAP SQL Anywhere 12.0.1.3152[1] .db and .log file. I don't have access to the source database, only these two files.

This is an ARGUS database of public records I'd like to make publicly available (via BigQuery).

However, I've not found any free, unix version of SAP I could use to read it and export to something usable (eg csv, json, MySQL dump, etc).

How can I extract this data, using free tools (preferably on Ubuntu)?

[1] My guess of the data format is based on the first line of the .db file, which has the string `WIN_LATIN1windows-1252UCAUTF-8` and many repetitions of `Sybase Inc., Copyright (c)2000 12.0.1.3152`.

For scale:

`$ du -m *
736     Argus12.db
2170    Argus_new.log
$ wc *
  10943417   44373930  771203072 Argus12.db
  38517623   83903318 2275373056 Argus_new.log
  49461040  128277248 3046576128 total`

Comment: SQL Anywhere runs on Windows, so your best best is to get a demo version of the software, and extract the data.

Answer (score 1):

The files you have *are* the database. Assuming you have a userid / password for the database, you can use the SQL Anywhere developer edition (available [here](https://www.sap.com/cmp/syb/crm-xu15-int-sqldevft/index.html)) on either Windows or Linux to run it and get the data from it.

*Disclaimer: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*